# iOS app/game crashes with scene update failed message after launching using Libgdx and robovm

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

I have created a libgdx app using robovm backend for iOS. When running the app on ios device, it crashes. When searching for my app id name, the console shows an error like this

FBSceneManager/sceneID:xyz.uniqeappname-default update failed: <NSError: 0x28385b960; domain: FBSceneErrorDomain; code: 1 (operation-failed); reason: "Scene update failed."> {
NSUnderlyingError = <NSError: 0x28243ff60; domain: FBWorkspaceScene; code: 1; reason: "Client process exited.">;
}

I am using gdx dialogs library also. https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-dialogs/tree/master

I tried searching for the cause, but found this only. https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/692182

Answer (score 0):

In console, I was filtering the messages by using my app name.

When I filtered using **IOSLauncher** keyword, it shows that class definition for gdx-dialog is not found.

Found that I haven't added ios dependencies. After adding the crash was gone.